# How does a strong selector override an id selector? Isn't an id selector considered more specific?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

in the following snippet, how come the **strong** selector overrides the **id** selector? Isn't an **id** selector considered more specific, thus having priority?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Sample document</title>
  <style>
      strong{color:red;}
      #abc {color:blue;}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="abc">
      <strong>C</strong>ascading
      <strong>S</strong>tyle
      <strong>S</strong>heets
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing is being overridden because you're targeting two different elements. This isn't related to specificity.

Comment: Thanks, But aren't the letters in the <strong> tag also inside the p #abc?

Comment: Yes but strong has `color:red`, it does not have `color:inherit`

Comment: `strong` supersedes `#abc` because the `#abc` style is only *inherited* for the contents of `<strong>`.  Yes, `#abc` is *more specific* in terms of naming but when rendering `<strong>` it is only inherited (less specific than a direct style rule).  If it was a `<strong id="abc">` then absolutely, you would be correct and the text would be blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct with specificity, but selectors only work with the direct content of the element. So the text color is different for the `strong` elements because it is nested deeper and the `p` selector isn't able to change the color for those elements. So if you did want to change the strong elements for `#abc` you would do it like this

```
strong { color: red; }

#abc strong {  color: blue; }
```

and if you wanted `strong` tags text to be the same as the `p` text then you would do this

```
#abc, #abc strong { color: red; }
```

```css
strong { color: red; }
#abc strong {  color: blue; }
#def, #def strong { color: red; }
```

```html
<p id="abc">
  <strong>C</strong>ascading
  <strong>S</strong>tyle
  <strong>S</strong>heets
</p>
<p id="def">
  <strong>ABC</strong>
DEF
</p>
```

Comment: Due to the fact that it is nested?

Comment: yes. i doesn't make sense when specifying a color for `p` text, then every element inside that tag gets that color.